# How to make a subscriber offline in iOS using cocoaMQTT

Tags: ios, swift, activemq-classic, mqtt

I am working on iOS using swift. I am using cocoa mqtt protocol using in my iOS app.
I am also using Activemq for message broker.

**Objective**

I have subscribed on a topic that is made on **ActiveMQ**. After that when I unsubscribe from topic on ActiveMQ then I want to the user remain subscriber of the topic but do not receive the messages. It gets offline.

I want that when subscriber again gets active than he can consume the pending messages from the topic.

**Problem Statement**

When I unsubscribe from the topic, the user is no longer a subscriber of topic and all the messages that are sent on the topic gets lost ( I do not receive them) that I get in the period on unsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem would be using the retained messaging functionality built right into MQTT. You will then receive the last message published on every topic, even when you've already received them in a previous session.

Another solution would be to use QoS 1 or 2 on the sent messages. If your app connects with `cleanSession` set to `false` and the messages were published with QoS 1 or 2, you will receive the messages sent while disconnected from the broker.

Learn more about MQTT QoS [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels).